# jQuery mobile - Trigger event when user scroll to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to detect when user scroll to specific div element with class `.seller-info`
but `scrollTop()` method always returns 0

I've tried all of the examples here in stack, but still not working.
Here's my latest solution:

```
$('body').on({
    'touchmove': function(e) {
     console.log($(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Any ideas how could i detect it ?

Comment: its take body starting position.

Comment: But why it's still returning 0 as a result from scrollTop ?

Comment: actually what u want, if scroll reached div is trigger something? please check the below fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**I think Its helps to you**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
     alert('scroll reached!');
   }
});
```

```css
div {
    height:400px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Scroll Down</div>
<h1 id="scroll-to">I am The H1</h1>
```

Comment: It's not working, because $(this).scrollTop(); is returning 0. p.s i've already tried this example as i said above.